# Continuity at exactly one point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let consider the problem:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x \ & \ \mbox{ if } \ x \in \mathbb{Q}, \\ 0 \ & \ \mbox{ if } \ x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}. \end{cases}$$

I want to show that $f$ is continuous exactly one point and nowhere else. I know the sequential approach of continuity to the problem.

I want to prove it by the open set definition of continuity, that is, if  $V$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, we  prove $f^{-1} (V)$ is open.

Comment: Can you tell which is the only point of continuity?

Comment: $0$ is the only one point of continuity.

Comment: It can't be done; continuity at one point is a distinct notion. In particular the only open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ containing only rationals is $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The open set definition you quoted shows that a function is continuous everywhere on its domain. Your function is most definitely not continuous everywhere; as you noted in the comments, it's continuous only at $0$.

That said, there is a topological notion of continuity at a single point, using open sets. The definition says,

> A function $f : X \to Y$ is continuous at a point $x_0 \in X$ if and only if, for all open $V \subseteq Y$ containing $f(x_0)$, there exists an open $U \subseteq X$ containing $x_0$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$.

To show this, suppose $V \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ is open and contains $f(0) = 0$. Then we take $U = V$, which again contains $0$. For all $x \in U$, we have $f(x) = x \in U$, or $f(x) = 0 \in U$. Either way, $f(x) \in U = V$. That is, $f$ is continuous at the specific point $0$.

We can also use this to show discontinuity at other points. For example, if $x_0$ is irrational, we can take $V = (-|x_0|/2, |x_0|/2)$, which contains $f(x_0) = 0$. Suppose there is some open $U$, containing $x_0$, such that $f(U) \subseteq V$. As $U$ is an open set containing $x_0$, it must contain an interval $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$. We can shrink $\delta$ as much as we like, until we have $\delta < |x_0|/2$. Since the rationals are dense in $\Bbb{R}$, we can choose $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \cap \Bbb{Q}$. Then,
$$|f(x) - x_0| = |x - x_0| < \delta < \frac{|x_0|}{2}.$$
Therefore,
$$|x| \ge |x_0| - |x - x_0| > |x_0| - \frac{|x_0|}{2} = \frac{|x_0|}{2}.$$
This implies $f(x) \notin V$. That is, we have $x \in U$ such that $f(x) \notin V$, which contradicts $f(U) \subseteq V$, and hence $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$.

You can also come up with an analogous argument for $x_0 \in \Bbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$. I'll leave it to you to come up with the details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In your answer you wrote ....We can shrink $\delta$ as much as we like, until we have $\delta <|x_0|/2$. can you please tell me this more explicitly?

Comment: We are looking for an open interval $(x_0−\delta,x_0+\delta)$ contained in $U$. We know one exists, as $x_0\in U$ and $U$ is open. However, there is always infinitely many $\delta$ for us to choose from, because we can always choose a smaller $\delta$. The reason is, if we have $0<\delta′<\delta$, we always have $(x_0−\delta′,x_0+\delta′)\subseteq(x_0−\delta,x_0+\delta)\subseteq U$. If the $\delta>0$ we come up with is greater than or equal to $|x_0|/2$, then we can choose smaller $\delta′$,e.g. $\delta'=|x_0|/4<|x_0|/2<\delta$, and use it instead of $\delta$.