# Proof of function that is continuous at only one point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I am facing some trouble in the following problem:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x \ & \ \mbox{ if } \ x \in \mathbb{Q}, \\ 0 \ & \ \mbox{ if } \ x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}. \end{cases}$$

I want to show that $f$ is continuous exactly one point and nowhere else.

I have attempted it partially, but I am not sure about my solution.

My attempt:

We will prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$. Let $V$ be a neighborhood $f(0) = 0$. Take $U =V$, and it contains $0$. Then  $f(U) \subset V$. Thus, $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Now, we will prove the discontinuity of $f$ at any other points except $0$. Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R} -\{0\}$. If $x_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$, then   $V = (x_0 - \frac{|x_0|}{2}, x_0 +\frac{|x_0|}{2})$ is an neighborhood of $f(x_0) = x_0$ and  $0 \not\in V$. If $f$ were continuous, then there would always exist a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$  such that $f(U) \subset V$. But for such $U$, there  always exists a irrational number which belongs to  $U$, and then $0 \in f(U) \subset V$. Hence, $\textbf{contradiction!}$.

Thus, $f$ is not continuous at any nonzero rational points.

But, I want to know how should I proceed for nonzero irrational points which will lead a contradiction.

Comment: Your solution is good! I answered the other half [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4191127/continuity-at-exactly-one-point/). Note how similar it is to your approach.

Comment: Hi, @TheoBendit I just saw your answer. Can I conclude somethings from the followings?...Let $V = V = (-|x_0|/2, |x_0|/2)$ be open set containing $f(x_0) =0$.  By hypothesis, there would be a nbd $U$ of $x_0$ such that $f(U) \subset V$. But $f(U)$ always becomes $(U \cap \mathbb{Q}) \cup \{0\}$. Can I construct a contradiction from here?

Comment: I guess you could in a roundabout kind of way. It is true that $f(U) = (U \cap \Bbb{Q}) \cup \{0\}$. You would still need some kind of density argument to show that a rational point near $x_0$ will exist in $(U \cap \Bbb{Q}) \cup \{0\}$, but not $V$, so I don't think it becomes shorter or cleaner.

Comment: In your answer in the given link, you wrote .....we can choose, $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \cap \Bbb{Q}$. Then $|f(x) - x_0| = |x - x_0| < \delta < \frac{|x_0|}{2}$.  Can I avoid those ? Actually, I want to write since  $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \cap \Bbb{Q}$, then $|x-x_0|<\delta < \frac{|x_0|}{2}$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm not 100% sure how you'll use it, but what you've written is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If $x_0$ is irrational, let $x_n=2^{-n}\left\lfloor2^nx_0\right\rfloor$. Then $x_n\in(x_0-2^{-n},x_0]$ and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0$. On the other hand, each $x_n$ is a rational number, and therefore $f(x_n)=x_n$. So$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=x_0\ne0=f(x_0),$$and therefore $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$.