# Another proof of discontinuity of $f$ at irrationals

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x \ & \ \mbox{ if } \ x \in \mathbb{Q}, \\ 0 \ & \ \mbox{ if } \ x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}. \end{cases}$$

I want to show that $f$ is continuous exactly one point and nowhere else.

I have shown the following things:

1. $f$ is continuous at $0$.
2. $f$ is not continuous at nonzero rational points.

Now I want to show that  $f$ is  not continuous at irrational points (here I did not mention nonzero irrational , because .... irrational points are always nonzero).

I found a proof of discontinuity of $f$ by contradiction method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4191127/942638).

Actually, I am looking for a proof of discontinuity of $f$ at every irrational points as follows:

Let $V = (-|x_0|/2, |x_0|/2)$ be an nbd of $f(x_0) = 0$. If $f$ were continuous, there would exist  a nbd of $x_0$ such that $f(U) \subset V$. I want to show that there exist an element in $f(U)$ which is not in $V$. Then I would say a contradiction! I want to proof it like this....

To prove it I have the following tools:.

1. $f(U) = (U \cap \mathbb{Q}) \cup \{0\}$.
2. Density property of rational and irrationals.

But I have no idea how to proceed like the above.

Comment: In an $\epsilon\delta$ proof, simply try $\delta=\min\{\epsilon,\frac{|x|}2\}$ (works for $x\ne 0$, be it rational or irrational.

Comment: Sequentially definition of continuity is a lot easier.

Comment: Actually, I want to use ....A function $f : X \to Y$ is continuous at a point $x_0 \in X$ if and only if, for all open $V \subseteq Y$ containing $f(x_0)$, there exists an open $U \subseteq X$ containing $x_0$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$.

Comment: My answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787111/continuity-of-un-plottable-piece-wise-defined-function/2787259#2787259) is a great generalization of this question. It doesn't answer your question since you make more specific comments about continuity, but it is still super useful.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\delta>0$ and consider the interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$. If $x_0>0$, take $y\in(x_0,x_0+\delta)\cap\Bbb Q$ and then$$f(y)=y>x_0>\frac{x_0}2=\frac{|x_0|}2.$$So, $f(y)\notin\left(-\frac{|x_0|}2,\frac{|x_0|}2\right)$. And if $x_0<0$, you take $y\in(x_0-\delta,x_0)\cap\Bbb Q$ and a similar computation applies. Since any neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ contains some interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ in $\Bbb R$ be irrational. Suppose that $f$ were continuous at $x$, i.e.:

$$\forall O \subseteq \mathbb{R} \text{ open }: \left(f(x) \in O) \to (\exists U \subseteq \Bbb R \text{ open }: (x \in U \land f[U] \subseteq O)\right)\tag{1}$$

Now $f(x)=0$ so find some open set $O$ containing $0$ and such that $x \notin \overline{O}$ and apply $(1)$ to it to find open $U$ containing $x$, so that $f[U]\subseteq O$.

As $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, there is some rational $q \in U \cap \overline{O}^\complement$, which is an open neighbourhood of $x$ so intersects $\Bbb Q$.
But then $q = f(q) \in f[U] \subseteq O$ which contradicts $q \notin O$ (as $q \in \overline{O}^\complement \subseteq O^\complement$).

So $f$ is not continuous at $x$. You can e.g. take $O = (-\frac{|x|}{2}, \frac{|x|}{2})$ if you want to be specific in the choice of $O$.

This is the essence of the argument.

Comment: @user092022 true, I'll edit; I swapped the values in my head.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I want exactly. But i have some confusions. I want to know why you wrote $x \not\in \bar{O}$. I know that this means there is a nbd of $x$ which does not intersec $O$.

Comment: I belive that if we work with the particular case of $O$ i.e. $O = (-\frac{|x|}{2}, \frac{|x|}{2})$, then we do not need to consider the case $x \not\in O$, because in any case $x not\in  (-\frac{|x|}{2}, \frac{|x|}{2})$ Is it correct?

Comment: @user092022 there *is* no case distinction at all in my proof. I just need $x$ is not in the closure of $O$ and that is certainly the case for that concrete $O$.